# Foxpro form control "object not found" (but it existed in the form!)

Tags: forms, foxpro, visual-foxpro, mouseclick-event

I am trying to make a simple Form in Foxpro, I create the Form name form1, drag two CommandButton Command1 and Command2, In the Click event of Command1:

```
Command2.Visible = false
```

When I click, the Error message is: Object "Command2 cannot be found"

I worked in .Net so this is so strange

Comment: As an aside, I had similar conceptual issues as a FoxPro developer when I started working with Windows Forms over 10 years ago. The Visual FoxPro GUI object system is based on containers (like a form) that can hold controls, or other containers. So to reference other form components you usually need to reference the object hierarchy as in the answer below. It is good practice also to use form classes as opposed to forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This.Parent.Command2.Visible = .f.
```

or

```
Thisform.Command2.Visible = .f.
```